# Matching two values of different types in two SQL databases

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, mariadb

I am trying to compare records between two different SQL tables/databases in my Node project and have to do some transformation in order to compare the values.

In one database (MariaDB) the value is of type `INT`, and looks like this: `516542`

In the other (SQL Server) database the value I need to match to is of type `char(21)`, and looks like this: `00000516542-000`

What I tried doing was this:

```
WHERE (REPLACE(LEFT( LM301.DOCNUMBR, CHARINDEX('-', LM301.DOCNUMBR)), '-', '')) = 516542
```

This works for some records, but for others I get this error:

> "The conversion of the varchar value '0004000009123' overflowed an int
>   column."

If I pass the first value in as a string ('516542') it doesn't match at all.

How can I handle this scenario?

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Mariadb?

Comment: First db is MariaDB, second is SQL Server. Added those details above.

Comment: Did you try CAST('516542' AS INT) in sql server?

Comment: is this error on the sql server side? how are you joiing sQL to MARIA? linked server? My first thought is that the value 4000009123 is outside the bounds of a SQL Server int (2,147,483,647), try forcing type conversion to bigint?

Comment: Why have different datatypes on the different servers???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is at least correct. But from your example i can't determine whether the conversion is right or not.

Basically, somewhere in your CHAR(21). There a value which is greater than int32, or SQL Server int type, in value. This value is: 2,147,483,648. 4,000,009,123 is greater than this max value as specified by the error message.

The DBMS, with this where statement, will try to do the operation and compare to all records, and it runs into an overflow. You could do a string compare instead. Or try an explicit conversion and convert it to bigint.

```
WHERE CONVERT(BIGINT, (REPLACE(LEFT( LM301.DOCNUMBR, CHARINDEX('-', LM301.DOCNUMBR)), '-', ''))) = 516542
```

It's doing an implicit cast to INT because that's your compare type, then overflows. Making the conversion explicit allows you to determine the datatype instead.

Basically what's happening:

```
IF ('21474836480' >= 100) --Implicit conversion: Error and prints false
    PRINT 'True'
ELSE
    PRINT 'False'

IF ('214748364' >= 100) --Implicit Conversion: True
    PRINT 'True'
ELSE
    PRINT 'False'

IF (CONVERT(BIGINT, '21474836480') >= 100) --Explicit Conversion: Prints True
    PRINT 'True'
ELSE
    PRINT 'False'
```

So wrapping your value in an explicit conversion should resolve your error.

Comment: This works for some records, but for others I get an error trying to convert to BIGINT.

Comment: @Ademo What error are you getting? If it can't convert to bigint, it suggest your char strings contain non numeric characters that are not being replaced. I can't determine that based on your earlier post.

Comment: I'm going to try a few more records at a time to determine where the issue is. Might very well be some bad data somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do explicit *type* conversation with `TRY_CONVERT()`:

```
TRY_CONVERT(BIGINT, LEFT(LM301.DOCNUMBR, CHARINDEX('-', LM301.DOCNUMBR + '-') - 1)) = 516542
```

`TRY_CONVERT()` will return `NULL` if conversation fail.

You don't need to use `replace()`, you can subtract the position.

**EDIT :** `Try_CONVERT()` is available from `2012 +`. For older version you can do :

```
(CONVERT(BIGINT, LEFT(LM301.DOCNUMBR, CHARINDEX('-', LM301.DOCNUMBR) - 1)) = 516542 AND
 CHARINDEX('-', LM301.DOCNUMBR) > 0)
)
```

Note : This might fail if `DOCNUMBR` doesn't have numeric value prior to `-`.

Comment: @Ademo. . . That says some `DOCNUMBR` don't have a `-`. I added.

Comment: From within my Node project where I'm executing the function with the `mssql` package, I get this error: `"'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name."` Is `TRY_CONVERT` valid syntax for SQL Server?

Comment: @Ademo. . .  `Try_CONVERT()` is available from `2012 + `.

Comment: Works for me in SQL Server, but not when I run it from Node via the `mssql` package. So perhaps the package can't handle that yet.